# Qt paintEvent crashes

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, paintevent

Im trying to draw simple board on my widget.

When I'm trying to automatize this, my paintEvent crashes. I think it is caused by for loop inside, am I right? How to paint it in other way?

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
QPixmap myPix( QSize(20,20) );
QPainter painter(this);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i+5){
    painter.drawLine(QPointF(i,0),QPointF(i,max));
}
this->setPixmap(myPix);
}
```

Comment: Are you defining `max` somewhere, or have you accidentally passed the address of a function to QPointF?

Comment: I think `this->setPixmap(myPix);` produces a recursive call of your paint event.

Comment: Yes, max is just some float value, i set it when i'm loading some data from text file, it just max height of widget.
I deleted this line with setPixmap but it didn't help (generally I deleted declaration of myPix too :) )

Comment: @vahancho I think that I should disagree with you, I added explanation in my answer why setPixmap in paintevent does not produce infinite recursive.

Comment: @Chernobyl, nice, but your answer does not seem to explain why this code crashes.

Comment: @vahancho Why? First lines of my answer `i+=5` instead of `i+5` Loop is wrong. OP agree with this

Comment: @Chernobyl, Ah, I see now. Sorry. Still the infinite loop...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your for loop is incorrect and causes the program crash (I'm sure that's not your fault here). It should be written like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i+=5){
    p.drawLine(QPointF(i,0),QPointF(i,max));
}
```

i.e. with an *assignment* of the increment. This way it will do the job and finish properly.

On a side note, I would suggest to use [`drawPixmap()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawPixmap) instead of  `setPixmap()`. But `setPixmap()` will not cause infinite recursion and for example next code works properly.

```
//...
this->setPixmap(QPixmap("G:/2/qt.jpg"));
QLabel::paintEvent(event);
```

Why? With this approach infinite recursion is never produced (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#repaint)):

> If you call repaint() in a function which may itself be called from
>   paintEvent(), you may get infinite recursion. The update() function
>   never causes recursion.

Indeed `setPixmap()` calls `update()`, not `repaint()`. To prove that see source code:

[setPixmap source:](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/1a57e3eec9dc0fe6381d3e5bf161df150fe3e115:src/gui/widgets/qlabel.cpp#L421)

```
void QLabel::setPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap)
{
    Q_D(QLabel);
    //...
    d->updateLabel();//what it does?
}
```

[updateLabel source:](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/1a57e3eec9dc0fe6381d3e5bf161df150fe3e115:src/gui/widgets/qlabel.cpp#L1208)

```
void QLabelPrivate::updateLabel()
{
    Q_Q(QLabel);
    //...
    q->updateGeometry();
    q->update(q->contentsRect());//not repaint

}
```

As I said it is not a mistake but I think that it will be better if you will do all what you need with `QPainter`.

Comment: It works! My God, why I didn't see this on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to obtain such a board as the background of the widget instead of repaint it in paintEvent?

Comment: You say *I would suggest to use drawPixmap() instead of  setPixmap()*, but in your code snippet you have `this->setPixmap(..)`.. thats a little confusing.. is that a mistake?

Comment: @thuga As you can see, my answer was edited, you can see my previous (unedited) answer(see edit history), it has no perfect grammar, but it was clear. I did not see that my answer was edited not correctly, so I edited it. Main idea was to prove that setPixmap inside paintEvent does not cause recursive paint

Comment: @Tatarinho See this please: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent Pay your attention on setPalette. As you can see, you should use paintEvent or methods like setPixmap, setPalette and so on.